# VBA - Runtime error with END IF

Tags: excel, error-handling, runtime, vba

I am relatively new to VBA. And when I was working on a worksheet I created a code that automatically hides/unhides rows based on a condition in a column row (0 unhide/1 hide). This relatively easy macro worked well until I added a different sheet. As there are no macros in this sheet I dont think it is related. But now everytime it gives a runtime error on the END IF function and I don't know how to solve it. There is probably a simple solution, but I cannot find it.

Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "BA").End(xlUp).Row
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each c In Range("BA34:BA56,BA73:BA74,BA76:BA107")
        If c.Value = 1 Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf c.Value = 0 Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Probably not the source of your error but you could encompass that whole `If ... Else ... End If` as `c.EntireRow.Hidden = CBool(c.Value)`

Comment: Does that error say *anything* more than "runtime error"?

Comment: Remove or comment out the `On Error Resume Next` and apply a parent worksheet reference to the range object. The worksheet may have volatile formulas that are triggering a calculation event due to changes on the other worksheet.

Comment: What is `LastRow` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Does this have to run if the parent worksheet is not active? Could changes in another worksheet affect column BA in this worksheet?

Answer (score 1):

Remove or comment out the `On Error Resume Next` if you want more complete debugging information. It should not be necessary in an event macro that runs as often as Worksheet_Calculate.

Apply a parent worksheet reference to the range object. The worksheet may have volatile formulas that are triggering a calculation event due to changes on the other worksheet.

I've added a wide condition so that the code will only run if the parent worksheet holds the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx). The worksheet may have volatile¹ formulas that are triggering a calculation event due to changes on the other worksheet (or even another workbook).

`LastRow` does nothing after its assignment (which is problematic) so I removed it.

I simplified the [Range.Hidden](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834657.aspx) property to a single line.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Me.Name = Activesheet.Name Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim c As Range
        For Each c In Me.Range("BA34:BA56,BA73:BA74,BA76:BA107")
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = CBool(c.Value2)
        Next c
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your response. Indeed the initial error was only runtime error and it took a long time for the macro to work. The Sheet is just "Sheet1". Replacing it with your suggestion it says  runtime error "1004". Thank you very much for your help and quick response.

Comment: Just to finish the thread. I solved it based on a combination of the code you wrote and mine, as the 0 should be the trigger to unhide as well. I guess the error line caused the issue.

Comment: I don't actually understand the problem since `CBool(0)` resolves to `False`. In almost any programming language, `False` equates to zero and in boolean terms, anything that is not false is true; e.g. #define False 0: #define True Not False.

Answer (score 0):

Just to finish the thread. I solved it based on a combination of the code you wrote and mine, as the 0 should be the trigger to unhide as well. I guess the error line caused the issue.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "BA").End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each c In Range("BA34:BA56,BA73:BA74,BA76:BA107")
       If c.Value = 1 Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf c.Value = 0 Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```